# Finite order of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

An element $a\in G$ has order $n$ if there exists $n$ such that $a^n=e$ (identity of a group) and if there doesn't exists such $n$ then the order of $a$ is said to be infinite.

Now my question is alternatively can we say that if such $n$ exists such that $a^n=e$ then the order of $a$ is  said to be finite order instead of order $n$? Can we use the definition of order of an element of a group for the definition of finite order of an element of a group?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). To say that $a$ has finite order is less precise than to say it has order $n$ for a given $n \in \Bbb N$. Take the matrix $A={\rm diag}(-1,1)$. It has order $n=2$ in $GL_2(\Bbb R)$, which is of course finite order.

Comment: The definition of the "order" is not correct. You have to add the condition that $n$ is minimal among all $n\geq 1$ with $a^n = e$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @DietrichBurde how do we define finite order of an element of a group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of an element $a$ in a group $G$ is the *smallest* positive integer $n$ for which

$$a^n=\underbrace{a*\dots *a}_{n\text{ times }a}=e,$$

where $e$ is the identity element of $G$ and the operation of $G$ is $*$; and it is indeed infinite if no such integer exists. The word "smallest" is very important.

Comment: And, whenever 'n'  is finite then the order of an element of a group is said to be of finite order. Is that right definition for the finite order?

Comment: Yes, @Keshavshrestha.

Comment: No: "whenever 'n' is finite" makes no sense. Either there exists such an integer $n$, and $a$ is said of finite order, or there doesn't, and $a$ is said of infinite order.